# Access image path for NetworkImageView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-volley

I am trying to get the image path of a NetworkImageView form a ListView but it returns null. In my `MainActivity.java` I use the following:

```
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      // get the title
      String _movieTitle = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
      // send the title
      myIntent.putExtra("title", _movieTitle) ;

      // get the image path
      NetworkImageView v = (NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
      String imgUrl = (String) v.getTag();
      ....
      // just for testing (works fine)
      System.out.print("title is " + _movieTitle);
      // image path is (returns null)
      System.out.print("Image path is " + imgUrl);
    }
}
```

content of `adapter.java` is as follow:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        ....
        // getting movie data for the row
        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

       // thumbnail image
       thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

       // title
       title.setText(m.getTitle());
```

content of `list.xml` :

```
 <!-- Thumbnail Image -->
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />

    <!-- Movie Title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

not sure why the image path returned in `MainActivity.java` is null. Can someone please have a look at this and see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You want "getRequestUrl()" ? > ImageContainer oldContainer = (ImageContainer) getTag(); ... oldContainer.getRequestUrl().equals(mUrl) https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/d62a616ebca5bfa4f9ec5517208e13f2d501b69a/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java

Comment: @Toris not sure what that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do too much unnecessary? Just do `String imageUrl = NetworkImageView.getImageURL();`

Comment: is `getImageURL` a method of volley? because I get cannot resolve method `getImageURL()`

Comment: In Volley of version 1.0.17, `NetworkImageView` has the method of `getImageURL()`, what's version of the Volley you are using?

Comment: oh okay, I just updated to that version and now the error changed to `error: non-static method getImageURL() cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: `v.getImageURL()` v is your `NetworkImageView` instance.

Comment: also a quick question, do you know how can I set the image url as the source image for Imageview? I tried [this](http://pastebin.com/mV8bpgwE) but it doesn't work

Comment: try `NetworkImageView.setImageUrl(imageUrl, ImageLoader)` to start downloading and setting an online image.

Answer (score 0):

New answer.

Set view.tag when you call setImageUrl()

In adapter.java

```
String imgUrl = m.getThumbnailUrl();
thumbNail.setImageUrl(imgUrl, imageLoader);
thumbNail.setTag(imgUrl);
```

---

I've checked current (master tree) version NetworkImageView and
it does not set tag (always null).

---

OLD answer.

MainActivity.java

> String imgUrl = (String) v.getTag();

Chage to

```
ImageContainer c = (ImageContainer) v.getTag();
String imgUrl = (null == c) ? "" : c.getRequestUrl();
```

---

from [NetworkImageView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/d62a616ebca5bfa4f9ec5517208e13f2d501b69a/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java) source

```
NetworkImageView.setImageUrl() or onLayout() calls
NetworkImageView.loadImageIfNecessary() {
    ...
    ImageContainer newContainer = mImageLoader.get(mUrl, ...
    setTag(newContainer);
    ...
}
```

---

from [NetworkImageView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/d62a616ebca5bfa4f9ec5517208e13f2d501b69a/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java) source

```
public class NetworkImageView extends ImageView {
/** The URL of the network image to load */
private String mUrl;
...

ImageContainer oldContainer = (ImageContainer) getTag();
// if there was an old request in this view, check if it needs to be canceled.
if (oldContainer != null && oldContainer.getRequestUrl() != null) {
    if (oldContainer.getRequestUrl().equals(mUrl)) {
    // if the request is from the same URL, return.
    return;
...
}
```

This shows "oldContainer.getRequestUrl()" can be compaired with "mUrl" and
it means getTag().getRequestUrl() returns url.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I get this error `error: cannot find symbol method getRequestUrl()`

Comment: I've downloaded volley master tree and checked NetworkImageView. It does not set mTag. So, set tag with view.setTag(uri) when you set image uri is an alternate answer.